# How do I link selections on two different layer masks in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop-cs5, masks, image-manipulation, layers

I've created my own action in Photoshop CS5 and in my example I am recolouring grass.

The action stops for the user to paint a selection on a layer mask and continues with a colour balance adjustment.

The action then continues to use the selection mask from the first layer and another mask is created, this time the user adjusts the hue/saturation.

On occasion, after I've changed the hue/sat there are some areas on the masks that I've missed.  Is there any way I can make adjustments (in this case painting/selecting) the second layer and have it linked to the first layer so I don't have to paint/select both layers individually? Right now when I want to include more selection area I have to repaint the selection on both the colour and the hue/sat layer masks.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to the [Graphic Design stackexchange site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Why is that...?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall - Based on a discussion in meta it was determined that these Photoshop specific questions do not belong in the Photography SE.  http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/658/what-should-we-do-with-photoshop-questions

Comment: That's where the question doesn't relate to photographic retouching: the FAQ says questions regarding photo processing and retouching are perfectly valid. Color balance and masking is surely a photographic use of PS, not a design one.

Comment: Have to agree with @Elendil here. This is definitely a photographic use of photoshop (correcting color balance.) Photoshop questions themselves are not inherently off-topic. They are only off topic if they clearly contain graphic design, print design, or non-photographic editing techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can easily do this with multiple masks.  You need to use a single mask, but clip your adjustment layers to that one mask.

Assume you have your main background layer called Layer1, a colour balance adjustment layer above that, and hue/sat adjustment layer on top.

1. Put the colour balance and hue/saturation layers in a group (I do this, not sure if it's a necessary step)
2. Create the mask only to the bottom of the two (the colour adjustment layer)
3. Alt-click between Layer1 and the colour adj layer to create a clipping mask.
4. If necessary, alt-click between the two adjustment layers to clip the hue/sat layer.

Now the mask will apply to both of your adjustments

Answer (score 0):

1. Paint in the desired changes to one of the layer masks.
2. Alt-Click the layer mask icon (the one you've edited) in the Layers palette to show the mask.
3. Select All and Copy
4. Alt-Click the other layer mask, Paste.

Comment: Ta, I can copy the mask to a second layer, but what I want now is when I go and make changes on the second layer, it will make the same changes on the first automatically, rather than copy/pasting (and hopefully can include whatever the link is in the recorded action).  I'm hoping there's a way to auto link the masks, but can use your work around in the meantime.